# Decompression speed (rate)

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science

I've heard that decompression speed or rate in which the gas will leave the greater pressured container is equal to the speed of sound.

For example, if the spacecraft gets damaged the air cannot exit out to vacuum faster than about 340 m/s

I don't understand how the flow rate of the fluid is determined by the density. Please explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I've heard that..."  is almost always identical to "it's not true."

Here's a paper which points out, among other that gas can move at 3x sound speed.

[The Expansion of a Gas-cloud into a Vacuum](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1953ZA.....33..251K)